# summing up string representation of year and month durations in ruby

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if there is a way to sum up multiple durations in string representations like `2 years 2 months`, `10 months`, `3 years` and output `6 years`

Comment: Thanks for the greenie, but consider removing it and waiting a while before making a selection (at least a couple of hours, say). Quick selections discourage other answers and may short-circuit others still working on answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that as follows.

```
str = "2 years 4 months, 10 months, 3 years, 1 month"

r = /
    (\d+)        # match one or more digits in capture group 1
    \s+          # match one or more whitespace chars
    (year|month) # match 'year' or 'month' in capture group 2
    s?           # optionally match 's'
    \b           # match a word break
    /x           # free-spacing regex definition mode

a = str.scan r
  #=> [["2", "year"], ["4", "month"], ["10", "month"], ["3", "year"], ["1", "month"]] 

h = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(n,period),h| h[period] += n.to_i }
  #=> {"year"=>5, "month"=>15} 
y, m = h["month"].divmod(12)
  #=> [1, 3] 
h["year"]  += y
  #=> 6 
h["month"] = m
  #=> 3 
h #=> {"year"=>6, "month"=>3}
```

Notes:

- As noted in the doc for [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan), "If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group."
- `Hash.new(0)` creates an empty hash with a default value of zero, meaning that if that hash `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns zero. Thos is sometimes called a *counting hash*. See the doc for [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).
- [Numeric#divmod](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) is a useful and greatly-underused method.

Comment: feature request: to work for singular months/years e.g. '1 year, 1 month'.

Comment: Thanks Cary. Look forward to using my remaining two wishes.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I am reminded of the Irishman whose second wish was for a bottomless beer mug. Whenever the mug became empty, it would magically refill. His third wish was for another such mug. (Don't worry about Irish readers--they can take it.)